# Using a function as an Action argument

Tags: c#, lambda, observablecollection

For my scenario I have `List<T> removable` that I'm using to remove items from my variable `ObservableCollection<T> collection`. I don't believe I can use the `Except` method here because I need `collection` to create change events.

```
removable.ForEach(profile => collection.Remove(profile));
```

Is there a better syntax for passing a function as an `Action` argument? In Java I would just pass in the method:

```
removable.stream().forEach(collection::remove);
```

Comment: @GrantWinney I get an error for the return type doing that; remove returns a boolean

Comment: @GrantWinney also it just seems kinda unnecessary to have the additional lambda construct for forwarding a single parameter.

Comment: In Java you can pass the function IF THE PARAMETERS AND RETURN TYPE MATCH, exactly as in C#, so no, there's no better way to do it if the function signature is not the same, like in Java.

Comment: @Gusman  this seemed to run fine; are you sure? https://ideone.com/4aUYJo

Comment: @Gusman ah nevermind, i think I get it. C# uses `Action<T>` with an always `void` return type, and java uses `Consumer<? super T>` allowing for any return type.

Comment: hehehe, yes, it is :), in this case you would need a ForEach accepting a Func<TOut, TIn> not an Action<T> as it does.

Comment: You can always add an extension to IEnumerable<T> which accepts it.

Comment: @Gusman trying to do that now as an exercise, but I'm having some trouble. I'd accept an answer that shows me how! :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java you can pass the function if the signature of the function matches, exactly as in C#, so no, there's no better way to do it if the function signature is not the same, like in Java.

But, you can always create an extension to accept any return type, like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ForEach<TIn, TOut>(this List<TIn> TheCollection, Func<TIn, TOut> ProcessFunction)
    {
        TheCollection.ForEach((item) => ProcessFunction(item));
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
removable.ForEach<string, bool>(collection.Remove);
```

This is not faster but is more readable.

Comment: Can't get it to compile: https://ideone.com/2YxCea  Does it have anything to do with this extension being double generic vs the original single generic found in linq?

Comment: Your extensions must be in a sepparated static class, put it in another .cs file, it compiles for me.

Comment: Not sure what's up. I have it in a separate file, but it's still not finding the right definition for `removable.ForEach(collection.Remove);`. I'm using VS community 2015

Comment: Gosh, i had an error on my code, I called it ForeEach.. XD, sorry for that, you have two options, or call it explicitly telling the type of arguments (col.ForEach<string, bool>(col.Remove)) or you name it with another name so the compiler resolves it correctly.

Comment: LMAO! I can't believe I didn't see that either haha. is there any way to maintain type inference here? Oddly visual studio doesn't like it, but this website is cool with it now https://ideone.com/2YxCea

Comment: Nope, it seems inference does not take in account the return type, only the input parameters.